Placing randomly generated numbers into random positions in a row range
I would like to generate 5 random number between 1 and 49 and place them into a row range like A1:AA1 in 5 random positions. The empty cells should get a value of 0.
The basic concept is =RANDARRAY(1,27,1,49,TRUE). This almost works, but it fills in all the 27 cells. I need to somehow fill only 5 randomly chosen cells out of the 27 (e.g.: A1, G1, L1, M1, X1).
How can this be done?

Try this formula:
=LET(values,RANDARRAY(1,27,1,49,TRUE),
random5, TAKE(SORTBY(SEQUENCE(27),RANDARRAY(27,,1,27,TRUE)),5),
MAP(values,SEQUENCE(1,27),LAMBDA(v,i,IF(ISNA(MATCH(i,random5,0)),0,v))))

It erases from the initial 27 values all but 5 - which have been created randomly
random5: sorts a sequence of 27 randomly and takes top 5 values.
These values are then used as index of those that are kept - all other values are returned as 0.

This is one solution:
=IF(SORTBY(SEQUENCE(,27),RANDARRAY(,27))>5,,RANDARRAY(1,27,1,49,1))


This is a solution without duplicate values:
=IF(SORTBY(SEQUENCE(,27),RANDARRAY(,27))>5,,TAKE(SORTBY(SEQUENCE(,49),RANDARRAY(,49)),,27))



Here is what I am proposing to use, which I have commented above as well:


=BYCOL((TAKE(UNIQUE(MAP(SEQUENCE(27),LAMBDA(q,RANDBETWEEN(1,27)))),5)=SEQUENCE(,27))*
  TAKE(UNIQUE(MAP(SEQUENCE(27),LAMBDA(q,INT(RAND()*100)))),5),SUM)



Generate Random Integers
=LET(bottom,1,top,49,size,27,sample,5,replacement,0,
    c,top-bottom+1,
    SORTBY(EXPAND(TAKE(SORTBY(SEQUENCE(,c,bottom),
        RANDARRAY(,c)),,sample),,size,replacement),
        RANDARRAY(,size)))

